# How to write Javascript audio blob to Python wave?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, mediarecorder, mediadevices

I'm trying to create a Flask endpoint that accepts an audio blob every n seconds and write it to a wave file:

**Flask:**

```
@app.route('/api/v01/post/audio-blob/', methods=['POST'])
def api_post_audio_blob():
    blob = request.data
    with open('file.wav', 'ab') as f:
        f.write(blob)
    return Response(status=200)
```

**Javascript:**

```
const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

    /* Get client-side audio stream */
    var constraints = { audio: true }
    var chunks = []
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {
        const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        recorder.ondataavailable = event => {
            chunks.push(event.data);
            var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                type: "audio/wav"
            });
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v01/post/audio-blob/";
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "audio/wav");
            xmlhttp.send(blob);
        };
        recorder.start(10000);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        /* handle the error */
    });
```

It seems like binary is written to file.wav, but it doesn't play any sound. Anyone knows how to resolve this? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nope, the data is being transferred, the file is playable, sound is available. Please keep in mind that the recording is only finished when the recorder is stopped. This could make your code less buggy on both sides. But your example works for me.

Comment: Thank you for running the code. If it works on your end, there's probably something wrong with my microphone input settings. Also agree that explicitly stopping the recording will help to make it less buggy. Will try to resolve it later today!

Comment: It indeed worked. I tried another audio player, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the code above works. Tried another audio player which resolved the 'issue'