# Google Speech Diarization label changes all the time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm buidling an application to transcribe a real-time audio stream using [Google Speech-To-Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) with [speaker diarization](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices) enabled (see previous questions for background: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154282/how-to-create-wav-stream-in-javascript-with-help-of-recordrtc), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970153/how-to-write-javascript-audio-blob-to-python-wave), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552461/google-speecht-to-text-diarization-python-sdk)). Ideally, the output should look something like this:

```
00:00, speaker 1: 'Hello Peter, how old are you?'
00:08, speaker 2: 'Hello Mary, I am 20 years old.'
00:14, speaker 1: 'Where do you live?'
00:19, speaker 2: 'I live in New York.'
```

While my current Google STT setup transcribes the input audio relatively well, speaker diarization doesn't work as I expect it. Google sends the entire transcript in each response, but each time the speaker labels (*i.e.* speaker 1 and speaker 2) are changing for previously recognized text. I have implemented Google's example Python script:

```py
    # google speech client is configured and instantiated before this

    response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
        
        result = response.results[-1]
        
        words_info = result.alternatives[0].words
        
        for word_info in words_info:
            print(
                u"word: '{}', speaker_tag: {}".format(word_info.word, word_info.speaker_tag)
            )
```

Here's example output of the first response:

```
word: 'hey', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'Peter', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'hello', speaker_tag: 2
word: 'Mary', speaker_tag: 2
```

But the next response gives:

```
word: 'hey', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'Peter', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'hello', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'Mary', speaker_tag: 1
word: 'how', speaker_tag: 2
word: 'are', speaker_tag: 2
word: 'you', speaker_tag: 2
word: 'doing', speaker_tag: 2
```

Does the model keep updating while new audio is arriving as input? If so, what would be a good approach to create transcription service with multiple speakers in one audio stream?

I don't expect a silver bullet, but hopefully someone can point me into the right direction.

Comment: The speaker diarization feature of speech to text is still in beta, thus its features are still not stable and may not perform well. It is not yet recommended to use this feature yet in production (if ever your planning to). There are publicly known issues for this feature and the Speech API engineering is working on it. https://issuetracker.google.com/137168930 https://issuetracker.google.com/170295821

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check out if this issue has already been raised. If not I will raise the issue with the Speech API engineering team. In the meantime, are there any other speech diarization services that are more stable?

Comment: There are already multiple issues raised like the links I gave from my previous comment, but feel free to raise another issue. You can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) for reference on how to create a issue. It is much better to post another question so that the community can provide their insights regarding other speech diarization services.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't click on your links before I responded. Let me post a new question about speech diarization services and see if it's necessary to raise this particular issue again with the Google egineeering team. Thanks for the help anyway, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should add this ::: `enable_word_time_offsets=True`

```
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    language_code="en-US",
    enable_speaker_diarization=True,
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    diarization_speaker_count=2,
)

for word_info in words_info:
    print(
        u"word: '{}', speaker_tag: '{}', start_time: '{}', 'end_time: '{}'".format(word_info.word, word_info.speaker_tag, word_info.start_time, 
                                                                                   word_info.end_time)
    )
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: Basically the question is about start time and end time of word through Google API that's I added ```enable_word_time_offsets=True``` for print the time.